"Heuristic" vs. Rigorous Ito's Lemma
Assuming $X_t$ is a standard Brownian motion and $t$ is the time variable, I have learned to derive Ito's lemma for a function $F(X_t, t)$ using the following results (below, $X_t=X(t)$, and I repeatedly make use of the scaling property $X(t)=\sqrt{t}X(t=1)=\sqrt{t}X(1)$):
For any finite $\delta t > 0$ and a standard Brownian motion $X_t$, we can argue that:
\begin{align*}
\tag{1}
\delta X_t := X(\delta t) \stackrel{d}{=}\sqrt{\delta t}X(1)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\tag{2}
\mathbb{E}[\delta X^2] = \mathbb{E}[\delta t X(1)^2]=\delta t
\end{align*}
And as $\delta t \to 0$ we can argue that ($X(1)=X$ for ease of notation):
\begin{align*}
\tag{3}
V(\delta X^2) = V(\delta t X^2]=\delta t^2 V(X^2) \to 0
\end{align*}
(the last results is true because $\delta t^2 \to 0$ as $\delta t \to 0$ and $V(X^2)$ = 3 using Moment Generating Function of a Normal distribution).
We can now define $\delta F:=F(X_0+\delta X_t, t_0 + \delta t) -  F(X_0, t_0) $ and use a Taylor expansion as follows:
$$\delta F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\delta t + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\delta X_t + 0.5 \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial X_t^2}\delta X_t^2+...$$
All higher order terms go to zero as $\delta t \to 0$, and using the results (1), (2) and (3) we can argue that $\delta X_t^2 \to \delta t$.
Using the notation $\delta t \to 0 \leftrightarrow\delta t \to dt$, we finally get:
$$dF=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} + 0.5 \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial X_t^2}\right)d t + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}d X_t$$
Question: the above is often described as a "heuristic" derivation of Ito's formula for $F(X_t, t)$. What would be "non-heuristic" (mathematically rigorous?) version of the derivation? What would be the key differences / how can I improve the "heuristic" argument above to make it more rigorous?

It's not rigorous because you need to argue very carefully that all of the error terms go to zero almost surely. It's possible that with positive probability, the error terms are non-negligible.

i.e. because Ito's lemma is true almost surely, you need to be careful in proving that things happen with probability 1, as opposed to in expectation or in probability

Jan Stuller: I don't claim to have read it but this looks like a "less heuristic" proof of Ito's Lemma. https://almostsuremath.com/2010/01/20/itos-lemma/

See the proof of theorem 3.3 on page 149 of "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus" by Karatzas and Shreve.
First of all, you need a rigorous definition of $dF$, i.e. a rigorous definition of stochastic integral. Second, you need to be more precise with the remainder of the Taylor expansion. Third, all your infinitesimal arguments have to be translated to statements about the stochastic/lebesgue integrals that they actually represent.
I can give some comments on the book's proof, which I think is good. The book considers a one dimensional process $X_t = X_0 + M_t + B_t$, where $M$ is a continuous local martingale, and $B$ is a process that is of bounded variation on each interval $[0, T]$. You can imagine that $M_t$ is standard Brownian motion. The book proves Ito's rule for $f(X_t)$ The proof in that book uses Riemann-esque sums to approximate $f(X_t) - f(X_0)$. Rather than explain, I'll just show you the picture for the key step:

For the rest of the proof, you write $X_t = X_0 + M_t + B_t$, expand the terms, and see which converge to a stochastic or Lebesgue integral and which vanish.
